# ERROR: NetworKit compilation requires cmake. #288

Tags: python, cmake, compilation, require, networkit

I use python3.7 and installed minGW has:

- GCC 8.2.0-3,
- CMake 3.13.3,
- Ninja 1.8.2,
- Cython 0.29.3,

but

```
pip install networkit
```

gives the error as follows:

```
C:\Users\anjali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install networkit
Collecting networkit
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/36/39298b5c1ddccd062505e7e2f9dcb14235ddd158008bda62cdbb907de8e3/networkit-5.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: NetworKit compilation requires cmake.
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\anjali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c4hcov67\networkit\
```

Could you provide a solution to fix this?

Comment: While importing NetworKit in a Linux VM ,found it as ' File not found '  in the link(https://networkit.github.io/uploads/networkit-vm.zip) provided. Could you provide the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kit-parco/networkit/issues/288).
In short, NetworKit Python builds are not yet supported on Windows, where it is only possible to build the NetworKit C++ core and use it as an external C++ library.
Possible solutions are to install NetworKit in a Linux VM or to use WSL.